# Совместимость Xcode с MAC OS.

Tags: xcode, ios

```
Скажите можно ли Xcode 4.6 установить на Mac os 10.5/10.6, или он станет только на 10.8?
Для работы с iOS 6 и iPhone 5 подходит только xCode 4.6 или можно воспользоваться более старой версией?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помоему нельзя, нужно в дев центре качать старую версию и новую SDK на сколько это возможно.

Comment: Ясно. Значит я могу скачать xcode 4.2 с пакетом сдк iOS 6.1.3?

Comment: теоритически, да. Из за глюкавости Xcode редкие люди его вообще обновляют :)

Answer (score 0):

У меня OSX 10.7, на него идет максимум xcode4.5, и там доступен iOS SDK с симулятором максимум до 6.0 версии